# Convergence rate of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

This problem needs more details but I can't write everything here. Please close this problem!

Let $(v_\epsilon)\subset W^{1,2}(I)$ where $\epsilon>0$ and $v_\epsilon\to 1$ in $L^1$ and $0\leq v_\epsilon\leq 1$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

My question: Does there exist $a$, $b>0$ such that if
$$
\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon^a}\int_I (1-v_\epsilon)^bdx<+\infty,
$$
then we have
$$
\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{(2t_\epsilon)^2}\int_{-t_\epsilon}^{t_\epsilon}(v_\epsilon(s))^2ds=0
$$
where $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}t_\epsilon=0$, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}v(t_\epsilon)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}v(-t_\epsilon)=1$, and there exists $-t_\epsilon<s_\epsilon<t_\epsilon$ such that $v_\epsilon(s_\epsilon)\to 0$.

Comment: If you deem this answer worthy of being closed, you should do it yourself.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I voted to close already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $v_\epsilon \equiv 1$. Then, your assumption is satisfied for all $a,b > 0$.

But
$$\frac1{(2t(\epsilon))^2} \int_{-t(\epsilon)}^{t(\epsilon)}1 \mathrm{d}s = \frac1{2t(\epsilon)} \to \infty$$
as $\epsilon \to 0$.

After the question has completely changed, still a similar construction is possible:
$$v_\epsilon(t) = \max\{1, n_\epsilon \, |t|\}$$
with carefully chosen $n_\epsilon$ (depending on $a$ and $b$).

Comment: I updated my post. Sorry for mistake before!

Comment: Hi gerw. I figured out how to do this problem. (Need some additional assumptions). But thanks so much for your counterexmaple!